# Linear acceleration data in android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to read Acceleration data both with gravity and without gravity.

For the data without gravity, I found that there is a sensor called `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`.

All the tutorials I have found talk about reading the data with gravity first, and then filtering out the gravity afterwards.

Which way is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` is certainly a *lot* easier. However, it was added in Android 2.3 (API Level 9). If your objective is to support only API Level 9 and higher, I would suggest `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`. If you are still aiming to support older devices than that ([which may not be worthwhile](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)), you will have no choice but to go the old way of subtracting out gravity yourself from `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`.

Comment: is it just lake reading data from accelerometer    linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0];
linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1];
linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2];